# While doing LINQ Queries i came across this issue while passing conditions

Tags: c#, linq

```
var JobList = new UpdateJobDetails();
JobList.jobDetails = (from b in Result 
                      where (b.JobStatus !=4 && b.ActionStatus != 0) || (b.JobStatus !=5 && b.ActionStatus != 0)  
                      select b).ToList();
```

If I do so this query is taking all the conditions as a separate entity.

So what i did is:

```
List<Jobs> Job = new List<Jobs>();
foreach (var item in Result)
{
    if ((item.JobStatus == 4 && item.ActionStatus == 0) || (item.JobStatus == 5 && item.ActionStatus == 0))
    {
        Job.Add(item);
    }
}
var X = (from b in Result
         where !Job.Any(x => x.ID == b.ID)
         select b).ToList();
JobList.jobDetails = X;
```

So here I just want to know can I achieve this through LINQ Query. As what I experienced Linq Query is not accepting combination of multiple conditions.
Correct me if I am wrong. 
TIA

Comment: I think you mean `!((b.JobStatus == 4 && b.ActionStatus == 0) || (b.JobStatus == 5 && b.ActionStatus == 0))`

Comment: Yes, you are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consider the following:

```
(a != 4 && b != 0) || (a != 5 && b != 0)
```

> `a` is different from 4 and `b` is different from 0, **OR**
>   `a` is different from 5 and `b` is different from 0

---

*Step added thanks to comments*

This is equivalent to:

```
b != 0 && (a != 4 || a != 5)
```

> `b` is different from 0 **AND**
>   `a` is different from 4 or `a` is different from 5

---

Well this is equivalent to:

```
b != 0
```

Because:

> `a` can not be both equal to 4 and 5

Now, just replace `a` with `b.JobStatus` and `b` with `b.ActionStatus` and you'll understand why your first query doesn't return what you expect.

---

### To answer your question

Yes you are wrong, Linq Query accepts combination of multiple conditions.

You only have to write good conditions.

This (condition in your `foreach` loop):

```
(item.JobStatus == 4 && item.ActionStatus == 0) || (item.JobStatus == 5 && item.ActionStatus == 0)
```

is *not* the **contrary** of (condition in your initial query):

```
(b.JobStatus !=4 && b.ActionStatus != 0) || (b.JobStatus !=5 && b.ActionStatus != 0)
```

If you want the contrary of:

```
(a == 4 && b == 0) || (a == 5 && b == 0) // 1)
```

which can be simplified to:

```
b == 0 && (a == 4 || a == 5)             // 2)
```

either use:

```
!((a == 4 && b == 0) || (a == 5 && b == 0)) // 1) basic negation
```

or:

```
(a != 4 || b != 0) && (a != 5 || b != 0)    // 1) ditributed negation
```

or even:

```
!(b == 0 && (a == 4 || a == 5))             // 2) basic negation
```

or:

```
b != 0 || (a != 4 && a != 5)                // 2) distributed negation
```

***The four above conditions are equivalent.***

Comment: No, it's certainly not `b != 0` even though a can't have multiple value at same time. You simply can't replace the condition in question with `b != 0`.

Comment: @Rahul Well then give me an example with `a` that will return `true` for `b = 0` or a value of `a` that will return `false` for `b != 0`

Comment: More like `b != 0 && (a != 4 || a != 5)`

Comment: @Kilazur well give me a value of `a` for which `(a != 4 || a != 5)` is `false` ???

Comment: @Rafalon well it's not what OP checking. Rather he is checking in composition/compound.

Comment: There are none, but the issue is probably not there. I think the author want an AND instead of an OR. He didn't put 4 and 5 here randomly.

Comment: @Kilazur Well my point **exactly** is that his conditions are wrong

Comment: @Rahul I'd like to know why this condition can not be replaced with `b != 0`. And my point is that it's what OP **should** be checking

Comment: @rafalon So you tell me you notice his condition is wrong, but still use it in your answer, just better written?

Comment: @Kilazur I analyzed his condition to show him **why** and **how** it's wrong.

Comment: @Rafalon why don't you try yourself and see

Comment: @Rahul well I'm sorry I can't see any `integer` value of `a` or `b` that could disprove what I wrote. That's why I asked you to prove me wrong, as you clearly are saying I'm wrong

Comment: @Rafalon In my for loop i am adding all those record i don't need then i am removing those from the main list. you can see on the next line

Answer (score 0):

Try below linq query ,

```
var JobList = new UpdateJobDetails();
JobList.jobDetails = (from b in Result where (b.ActionStatus != 0 && b.JobStatus !=4 && b.JobStatus !=5)  select b).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written the query seems wrong to me. you can re-write like

```
var JobList = new UpdateJobDetails();
JobList.jobDetails = from b in Result 
                     where ((b.JobStatus !=4 && b.ActionStatus != 0) || (b.JobStatus !=5 && b.ActionStatus != 0))
                    select b;
```

(OR) Use multiple `Where` conditions

```
JobList.jobDetails = Result
                    .Where(b => b.JobStatus !=4 && b.ActionStatus != 0)
                    .Where(c => c.JobStatus !=5 && c.ActionStatus != 0)
                    .Select(b => b);
```

Comment: Well, I don't think the problem comes from the parenthesis. `(a != 4 && b != 0) || (a != 5 && b != 0)` isn't this equivalent to `b != 0`?

Comment: Per your edit: `b =>` missing on second `.Where` **and** I'm quite sure using multiple `.Where`s act as **AND** and not **OR**, so the two queries written here aren't equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I tested all the solutions .where what i got.

1. My whole list 
   [image]
2. solution suggest by @Rafalon b != 0 && (a != 4 || a != 5) 
   [image]
3. Solution suggest by @vc 74
   [image]
4. Solution suggest by @Rahul 
   [image]
5. My previous one 
   [image]

So I got my desired result from the solution suggest by  @vc 74

Comment: I never claimed `b != 0 && (a != 4 || a != 5)` was the solution. You might want to re-read my answer.

Comment: Why don't you try to think *logically* instead?

Comment: i asked the question because i was in doubt . I appreciate your contribution. Thanks again :)

Comment: I edited my answer for any variant of your desired condition